# Changing a listview template content based on a property that is not part of the bound itemtype

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm using visual studio and the c# language to create a web application. My webpages are build using asp.net. I have a listview that uses the following itemtemplate:

```
<ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Panel runat="server" Visible="?????????" ID="ViewActions" >
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="content-action icon view" CommandName="View" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                </asp:Panel>

                <asp:Panel runat="server" Visible="?????????" ID="EditActions" >
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="content-action icon edit" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CssClass="content-action icon delete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Container.DataItemIndex %>' />
                </asp:Panel>
</ItemTemplate>
```

My listview is bound to the following itemtype:

```
ItemType="Web.Pages.CustomerItem"
```

In my code behind there is a boolean variable called "isInViewMode". This variable is not a property of CustomerItem, but a property of the code behind of my page. What I would like to do is, if "IsInViewMode" is true, then only the first panel should be visible. If it is false, only the second panel should be visible.

I know I can use `<%# Eval("Property") %>` to change the content of the listview based on the properties of each individual CustomerItem, but I do not want to make the variable "IsInviewMode" a part of my customerItem class, because it is either true for all customers or false for all customers.